# Xamarin Android: Handle Hardware Key in Spinner Dropdown

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've got an Android application written using Xamarin Android (not Xamarin Forms). It runs on a Zebra WT6000, which has hardware keys "P1" and "P2". By default, these are mapped to volume-down and volume-up (respectively).

Within my application, I use these keys for other things (and provide an alternative way for the user to manage audio volume). This all works as intended.

My problem is that I have a spinner (`Android.Widget.Spinner`), and when the spinner is tapped and the dropdown appears, the default button mappings come back in force, ignoring the key handlers in my activity.

I have tried this:

```
MySpinner.KeyPress += (sender, evt) => { /* do a thing */ };
```

and also:

```
MySpinner.SetOnKeyListener(new KeyListener());
...
private class KeyListener : Java.Lang.Object, View.IOnKeyListener
{
    public bool OnKey(View v, [GeneratedEnum] Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
    {
        // do a thing
        return true;
    }
}
```

However, neither my lambda function nor my `OnKey()` method ever get called, and the key handling doesn't change.

I suspect that the spinner's dropdown is its own `DialogFragment` (with it's own key handling) rather than part of my activity. If so, I suspect I have to call the `SetOnKeyListener()` of that `DialogFragment` (rather than the `SetOnKeyListener()` of the spinner).

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this (and by "way to do this" I mean "kludge"). The basic idea is that I have my own custom array adapter (derived from `ArrayAdapter`) to build the spinner rows. In its `GetDropDownView()` override, I set the `KeyPress` handler of the parent (where said parent is passed in as an argument).

Code:

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter<T> : ArrayAdapter<T>
{
    private bool ParentKeyHandlerHasBeenSet;
    ...
    public override View GetDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (!ParentKeyHandlerHasBeenSet && parent.Id == -1)
        {
            parent.KeyPress += (sender, evt) => { evt.Handled = true; };
            ParentKeyHandlerHasBeenSet = true;
        }

        return MyPrivateMethodThatBuildsTheView(...);
     }
}
```

That's obviously not a lovely, clean solution. If you have a better one, please share.

Comment: Since you are using a custom spinner adapter this is the only way I am aware of that you can do it, So I guess this is an okay solution in my understanding